# how to use ren/rename

Tags: cmd

I want to rename all my avi videos.

All the avi videos are in the current directory.
I do it like this 'ren ./original.avi new.avi'.
But it says the syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: This is on Windows? Try removing the `./`

Comment: I have figured it out.

I do it like this:
ren "original.avi" "avi.avi"

It works although weird.

Thanks guys.

Comment: YES, removing ./ is also necessary.
Thanks

Comment: Why weird? `/` isn't the directory separator on Windows, so there's no particular reason why `./something` should work at all. Furthermore you wouldn't need the `./` here in any case since your current working directory should be clear. You would need it on Unix-likes to run a program but never to just specify a file name (unless the file is named `-foo` or something, due to some braindead-ness of the shell on Unix-likes). In any case, `.\original.avi` should work as expected there, even though `.\\` isn't necessary.

Comment: @Joey I thought that Windows (i.e. the Kernel) handles `/` as a directoy separator just fine. It's just that cmd.exe is too dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with specifying the directory of the file you want to rename. However, on Windows you must use `\` instead of `/`:

```
ren .\original.avi new.avi
```

The `ren` command thinks you're trying to use one of its command line switches if you use the `/` character inside a filename. (It's not very smart.)

Comment: Yes, I should use '\'.
I have tried in xp and win7.
<ren .\original.avi new.avi> is not engouth.
<ren ".\original.avi" "new.avi"> can work.

Thanks